# Why can a compact surface not have infinite genus?

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for a point set topology argument for why a surface of infinite genus is sufficient for it to be noncompact. I've attempted arguments looking at an open cover around each "hole" having no finite subcover however, this doesn't give a cover of the whole surface. I've considered the surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and taking the topology induced from the metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and looking at sequences but have gotten nowhere. Is there a nice argument for why a surface of infinite genus cannot be compact?

Comment: What is your definition of genus?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm taking genus to be the maximum number of Jordan curves you can remove from the surface and it remain connected.

Comment: OK, then it becomes a theorem with a rather long proof. It is known that these curves are bicollared. From there, the proof is not too bad.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok thank you very much

Comment: I will try to locate a textbook reference, it uses homology as a tool.